# SpreadSheetGear - read unique values from Excel column

Tags: .net, excel, unique, spreadsheetgear

I want to read a column in Excel worksheet using SpreadSheetGear (.NET) and get unique values in that column back.

[image]

Example: From the above Excel worksheet, I need to read column B and get back unique values
"John"
"Mike" and
"Wayne"

In real life, there can be 1,000,000+ rows so efficiency is important.
How is that achieved?

Comment: Hello, Is it not as simple as Locking the View m_WorkbookView.GetLock(); then getting the Range SpreadsheetGear.IRange oRange = m_ViewLock.Workbook.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[aRowFrom, aColFrom, aRowTo, aColTo]; and reading from the range. You just add the names into a Dictionary and check whether they already are in the Dictionary before adding them. It seems so simple that I feel I am missing something obvious here

Comment: If you want a solution using formulas, take a look at the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429899/getting-unique-values-in-excel-by-using-formulas-only.

Comment: Another way of approaching this would be to choose a .net data structure that only allows distinct elements. Dictionary springs to mind here.

Answer (score 0):

I Understand that the post is quite old but could be helpful for others:
The comment entered by @Michael Moreno will be helpful and I endorse the idea. But the concern is: How one can judge the number of rows or columns to iterate the loop. For this I suggest the Property `IWorksheet.UsedRange` to get the range of data contained by sheet.
Curtsy by: @Chris in his [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509291/get-the-number-of-rows-of-data-with-spreadsheetgear)